# Inversion of return value

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a flag that I want to pass to a function which returns true or false based on a value in a map:

```
// userList is a List<String> and is stored as the value field in a map
// user is a String
if(flag)
{
    if (userList == null)
        return false;
    else if(userList.size() == 0)
        return true;

    return userList.contains(user);
}
else
{
    if (userList == null)
        return true;
    else if(userList.size() == 0)
        return false;

    return !userList.contains(user);
}
```

My question is this: is there anyway to tidy this code up, there is a lot of replication (the if and else block are identical, except their return values are the opposite of each other).

I'm not a very experienced code, and I'd really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: Move common code to another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `flag` value instead of constants.

```
if (userList == null)
    return !flag;
else if(userList.size() == 0)
    return flag;
```

A `XOR` will serve for the last statement (left as exercise to the reader :-p)

Answer (score 2):

We can move the common processing to its own method, then branch based on the `flag` variable as follows.

```
public boolean userExists(String user) {
    return userList != null && (userList.size() == 0 || userList.contains(user));
}
```

...

```
if(flag) return userExists(user);
else return !userExists(user);
```

As a side note, you may have a logic error.  I'm not sure why you'd want to `return true` in the case of `userList.size() == 0`.

Comment: Equivalently, the `if/else` part can be written like this instead: `return userExists(user) == flag;`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to simplify the whole snippet of code, removing the outer `if/else` statement:

```
if (userList == null)
    return !flag;
else if (userList.isEmpty())
    return flag;
return userList.contains(user) == flag;
```

Comment: Just use `==` instead of `!` accompanied by `^`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (userList == null)
    return !flag;
else if(userList.size() == 0)
    return flag;

return flag ? userList.contains(user) : !userList.contains(user);·
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove duplication by making the return value be a function of flag :

```
if (userList == null) {
    return !flag;
} else if (userList.size() == 0) {
    return flag;
}

return !flag ^ userList.contains(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return userList != null && userList.contains(user) == flag;
```

Might do the job.